# JSON.stringify longitud de cadena no válida

Tags: javascript, php, json

Tengo un problema al transformar de objeto a JSON.

Tengo un objeto que almacena entre 200 a 500 mb de información. Las imágenes se codifican en base 64 por lo que genera una cadena de texto demasiado extensa, y es aquí donde sucede el problema,

Por consola me arroja el error

```bash
"Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid string length at JSON.stringify"
```

Y quisiera saber si existe alguna otra manera de convertir de objeto a json o alguna función para poder evitar ese error.

Comment: Quieres regresar este objeto desde tu backend?

Comment: La pregunta es para qué necesitas serializar una imagen? Si necesitas que tu API (si es que ese es el caso de uso) devuelva una imagen, entonces no uses el formato JSON como respuesta, devuelve la imagen como un archivo. Si por otro lado, quieres guardar esa imagen, entonces guárdala en un Storage Binario (Amazon S3, Google Storage, etc)

Comment: puedes dividir tu objeto en un json (que contiene el objeto con las imágenes por referencia; y que devuelves al cliente) y sus imágenes (que guardas en binario), El cliente obtiene el objeto en json, lo parsea, y luego solicita las imágenes binarias por separado.

Comment: ¿Y si tuvieras que trabajar con vídeos harías lo mismo? No quiero imaginar el consumo de memoria al manipular, digamos 10 objetos de esos en tu aplicación. No parece algo muy práctico hacer lo que intentas. ¿Haz pensado en dejar las imágenes en su formato original y sólo intercambiar la ruta a las mismas para que se descarguen (si ese es el propósito del JSON) de una forma menos *costosa*?

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, si bien todas son acertadas pero aun no logro encontrar una solucion factible, debo agregar , que no lo hice en la publicacio, que estoy trabajando de manera offline, es decir, la web funciona con un pwa, donde almacena toda la info que llene en un formulario, en una base de datos del navegador (Indexeddb) y que cuando detecte internet, con un boton que dice sincronizar, envia esa info por POST, y tal como dicen, es una carga de datos inpresionante, en una visita a terreno se pueden llegar a llenar 100 formularios, con 10 imagenes cada una

Comment: y es ahi donde surge el problema que comente, en la publicacion

Comment: ponle un dexiejs encima ( las imagenes guardalas como blob ) y usa el sync https://dexie.org/docs/Syncable/Dexie.Syncable.js.html